# Android/Java. Как делать отладку приложения если нет устройства, на котором происходит exeption крах?

Tags: android, отладка, try-catch, android-debug

Приложение работает нормально на личном тестовом устройстве.. Но у других пользователей вылетает крах exeption.. в каких то моментах..
Вот как отследить и узнать в чем проблема если у меня нет таких реальных устройств?? и приложение сбойно аварийно завершается не показывая никаких логерроров..

Какие есть способы для отлова таких ошибок? Может библиотеки которые в случае краха отправляют на почту логеррорексепшон?

Или необходимо самому везде ставить вручную try catch? И выводить? Так получится?

Comment: я лично пользуюсь acra https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Answer (score 3):

Есть множество библиотек и фреймворков, попробуйте [fabric.io](http://fabric.io)